# File-Sharing and TCP does not work over MPLS

Tags: mpls

We have established an MPLS between two locations.  The DHCP helper is installed on the remote's router and we can ping devices from/to either subnet.  DHCP is working properly in both locations.

However, our internal website located at the host cannot be found from the remote.  The server's address is `192.168.1.20` and it works fine at the host subnet.  From the remote, we can ping `192.168.1.20` and get a reply, and we can also ping it's website name `my.internalsite.local` and get a reply indicating that DNS is able to translate the name into it's IP address.

There is no router or firewall between the remote computer and the host's server.

I confirm that the webserver's firewall (Windows 2003) is configured to allow traffic over port 80 from any address.

We cannot call up the website.

Nor can we access file-shares from the remote to the host.

We have confirmed that the ISP's routers (that run the MPLS) do not have any ports closed.

**[update]**

Running Wireshark (or nmap as I have done some time ago) shows me that communication via TCP is happening between the remote and the host just as you would expect.  If I type the remote address `\\192.168.2.249` into Windows Explorer of my host workstation at `192.168.1.236` I can see the TCP protocol being used.  When the TCP traffic reaches the destination, I see:

```
Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 53020 (53020), Dst Port: microsoft-ds (445), Seq: 0, Len: 0

Flags: 0x002 (SYN)
```

It seems like no TCP is being received.

Any clues what I might try?

Comment: Can you show a traceroute from a remote system to the web/file server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a list of a few things to try by way of troubleshooting:

- Try plugging in a computer directly into the MPLS ports on the MPLS routers so you can test without any other network equipment in-between.
- Set the gateway for each computer to be the MPLS port.
- Try testing with both computers running local administrator accounts - this will eliminate issues related to domain group policy and account-level access rights.
- Try enabling the option on your dhcp server for `netbios-name-servers 192.168.x.x`
- [Ensure there is a WINS server](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f337a90e-36a9-456e-bf9f-7216958d6c3a/mpls-setup-on-windows-servers) configured and running for the domain.
- Run your tests with the firewall off on both machines.

If those things don't work, it may be an issue with the routing tables within the MPLS cloud itself - which is what the problem was for my network.  Once they got the routing right I was able to access file shares.

As it turns out, the real problem was a network design error.  If you are interested in that, please read this other posting: https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6572/cannot-load-internal-website-over-mpls#6592

Comment: None of that stuff about accounts and WINS will have any effect on a website, which was one of the symptoms in your question.

Comment: The other symptom was about file-sharing. But no, it didn't solve the non-connectivity of my internal website.  If you have any suggestions as to how to fix it, I am all ears and am willing to change my accepted answer.

Comment: You said the actual problem was the vendor's to fix, so there you go.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some more troubleshooting.

1. Try telnet from the remote host to my.internalsite.local on port 80 (presuming it's serving pages on HTTP); if it connects, manually send a GET request for a known page.
2. Use Wireshark on one or both ends and see what's on the wire.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that and repost.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: What do you mean by "what's on the wire"?  What do I look for?

Comment: "On the wire" means the actual packets being transmitted. It's what a packet sniffer like Wireshark is meant for. You should be willing to do a little research on your own when confronted with a term that is new to you.